# Xamarin.Android Application not called anymore since XS 6

Tags: android, xamarin

In our team, we recently updated to Xamarin Studio 6, as it's just out. Unfortunately, Something just broke in our Android application.

Roughly, we have an `Application` class with initialisation in OnCreate().

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Application(Theme="@style/MyTheme")]
    public class MyApplication : Android.App.Application
    {
        public MyApplication (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base (handle, transfer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate ()
        {
            // Never called
        }
    }
}
```

But that `OnCreate()` isn't called anymore since we updated. A fellow dev reported that he reinstalled XS5, and still has the issue. This worked before, so something changed, but what?

Comment: I did a quick test with a new Xamarin.Android app and it works as expected. I'm on stable channel with X.Android 6.1.0.71. Please note that `OnCreate()` will only be called once if the app is started from scratch and not when starting a new activity. Likewise pushing the app into the background and resuming it will not trigger `OnCreate()` again.

Comment: I can also confirm that on the stable channel, XS 6.0 (build 5174) and Xamarin.Android 6.1.0.71 work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, new projects call `Application.OnCreate()` as expected.

I ended up creating a new project and drag/dropping all the files from one to another. Not nice, but at least it worked.

**EDIT:**

So here's what happened really.

Our application class inherited from another class, in a framework project, as follows:

```
class ParentApp
{
    void OnCreate()
    {
        SubclassInit();
    }

    abstract void SubclassInit();
}

[Application]
class MyApp : ParentApp
{
    void SubclassInit()
    {
    }
}
```

With this setup, nobody was called.

All we had to do is add an `OnCreate()` method in the `MyApp` class.

```
void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
}
```

And now it's solved.

Answer (score -1):

you must have to also update Android and IOS latest version with the Xamrin version